# Evernote oAuth error php

Tags: php, api, oauth, oauth-2.0, evernote

I'm having issues getting an access token from Evernote using oAuth in my codeigniter app.

I am able to successfully get my temporary credentials but when I ask for my access token. I get the following error.

> "Invalid auth/bad request (got a 401, expected HTTP/1.1 20X or a redirect)"

```
$_SESSION['requestToken'] = $requestTokenInfo['oauth_token'];
$_SESSION['requestTokenSecret'] = $requestTokenInfo['oauth_token_secret'];
$_SESSION['oauthVerifier'] = $_GET['oauth_verifier'];
print_r($_SESSION);
$accessToken = $client->getAccessToken($_SESSION['requestToken'], $_SESSION['requestTokenSecret'], $_SESSION['oauthVerifier']);
```

The print_r function correctly prints out the 3 parameters returned to me by Evernote as the temporary credentials.

I am using php 5.4.9 on an Ubuntu 12 server. I have installed the Pecl OAuth extension. Thank you very much in advance for any help.

Comment: The first example here http://php.net/manual/en/oauth.getaccesstoken.php shows passing a URL instead of the tokens. Does that help?

Comment: I am following the directions here:

https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-php

In the 2nd block of code under OAuth, it has the getAccessToken function with the 3 session params. That's where I'm getting the error

Answer (score 0):

To check if everything is working well, you should use their sample application.

To do so, clone the github repository you mentionned earlier, then edit the sample/oauth/config.php file by filling the variables :

```
define('OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY', 'your key');
define('OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET', 'your secret');

// Replace this value with FALSE to use Evernote's production server
define('SANDBOX', TRUE);
```

then go to http://your.domain.com/evernote-sdk-php/sample/oauth/index.php to test your settings and follow the steps that appears. At the end of the test you should have a list of all your notebook, or Error before it.

Once everything is done you can have a look at the code they provide as an example to understand how the PHP code works.

hope this help as this did the trick for me with python ;)